# Microsoft Server studio 'script table as' for INSERT to bad syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in a database that looks like this

[image: Database]

I want to insert a new record. So I right click on my table, hover over 'script table as' and select the 'INSERT to' option

When I do this, I get this

[image: query]

My question is, what is wrong with this syntax? I seem to be getting an error before even trying to add anything. When hovering over the red lines, I get a message saying

> 'Incorrect syntax near <'
>
> &
>
> 'varchar is not a recognized built in function name'

I assumed I would replace the second part with my data values. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to input actual values.

```
INSERT INTO tab_name(First_Name, Last_Name, ...)
VALUES ('John', 'Smith', ...);
```

Replace `<col_name, datatype>` placeholder with actual data.

---

You can also [`Use Templates in SQL Server Management Studio`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179334%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  to fill template values.

`Query` -> `Specify Values for Template Parameters`

or

Highlight your query and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: I see. I assumed that because Microsoft provided data types for the insert that I had to keep them after the actual value I was providing.

Comment: @onTheInternet This is template paramter, you can fill them in SSMS in GUI mode